# Reading from localstorage in nuxt js is not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, nuxt.js

i'm trying to read from locastorage in nuxt js.

i used process.browser if statement.
there is no error.

this is my code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      classes: ['light', 'dark', 'darker'],
      current: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (process.browser) this.getBgDarkness()

    console.log(this.classes[this.current])
  },
  methods: {
    makeBgDarker() {
      this.current < 2 ? (this.current += 1) : (this.current = 0)
      if (process.browser)
        window.localStorage.setItem('darknessLevel', this.current)
    },
    getBgDarkness() {
      this.current = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('darknessLevel'))
    }
  }
```

and this is my template:

```
<header :class="['header position-relative', `header--${classes[current]}`]"></header>
```

localstorage is set successfully and my `current` data is synced to it.

but my css class doen't change.

this is my console:
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTWCi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it seems to me it works. Try to remove all localstorage stuff to see if it works. There's no reason to not to...

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      classes: ["light", "dark", "darker"],
      current: 0
    };
  },  
  methods: {
    makeBgDarker() {
      this.current === this.classes.length - 1
        ? (this.current = 0)
        : (this.current += 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.header--light {
  color: yellow;
}
.header--dark {
  color: blue;
}
.header--darker {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div :class="['header position-relative', `header--${classes[current]}`]">Hello</div>
    <button @click="makeBgDarker">+</button>
</div>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```